# How say "You haven't a drive"?

Tags: word-request

I would like explain to my opponent what he has ability and knowledge, but he haven't a extreme spirit.

Russian language has word "drive", but I don't sure what it word has in English.
This word has relationship with extreme.

Example meta-phase:

> You good rider, but you don't have enough a drive
>
> You have the best show because you have a drive

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "extreme spirit", and I'm guessing between "ambitious" and "courageous". If you're talking about "ambition", you can say, *"You are a good rider, but you're not ambitious enough."* If it's about "courage", you could say, *"You are a good rider, but you don't have enough guts,"* or *"You are a good rider, but you don't have it in you!"*

Comment: No, not ambitiuos and not courageous

Comment: Sometimes we leave out the particulars and say things in a 'roundabout way like, "You just don't have what it takes."  Or, "You've got skill, I'll grant you that, but you still don't have what it takes."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact the word "drive" has the same meaning in English, but it is a mass noun, not a count noun, so it never takes the indefinite article "a." So you could say

You're a good writer, but you don't have enough drive.

Comment: Or "you have no drive".

Comment: Yes that is betterI

Comment: Or "you don't have the drive" (definite article rather than indefinite), though that might be a slight colloquialism.

Comment: @JAB that also sounds better to me

Answer (score 1):

When talking about someone's job or profession we normally use the indefinite article, a/an after the verb BE.
A *rider* could possibly be interpreted as being a professional motorcyclist or someone who does the sport for a hobby. If the OP wanted to convey this profession, then the word, motorcyclist, is more appropriate.

As alternatives to *drive* which answers the OP's question perfectly, there are the following

> You'**re a** good rider, but you don't have enough **determination** (to
>   win).
>   You have the best show because you have **dedication**

Further examples lifted from Merriam-Webster:

> It took a lot of hard work and
>   [dedication](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dedication),
>   but we managed to finish the project on time.
>
> What he lacked in talent he made up for in
>   [determination](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/determination?show=0&t=1387101797).

Comment: It is good word, but not for extreme

Comment: Determination is another way of saying *drive*. Often "[Drive and determination](https://www.google.com/search?q=Drive+and+determination&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs#channel=rcs&q=%22Drive+and+determination%22&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official)" are collocated together.